# центрировать окно jquery-confirm

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Всем привет.

Использую jquery-confirm библиотеку ( https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/ ). Вопрос в том, что она, выводя сообщения
при нажатии на кнопке удаления в списке ([ссылка](http://dev4.softreactor.com/admin/banner/index)),
отображает окно сообщения слева, а я хочу его центрировать.

В инспекторе объектов я вижу родительское окно со стилями:

```
jconfirm-box-container col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1
```

Насколько я понимаю этот код генерится библиотекой и его изменить нельзя?

Я пытался изменить стили в том числе и jconfirm-box-container(сейчас он зеленого фона для наглядности), но все равно окно слева.

Можно ли это окно центрировать и если да то как ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу, всему виной стили в inline-блоке `style` на странице (https://goo.gl/YBHfeg). В нем многократно встречаются правила

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: none;
```

которые и "ломают" стандартное поведение окна. Как вы можете увидеть на примерах на офф. сайте - там таких правил нет и окно ведет себя правильно. Так и у вас, если отключить эти правила.

С другой стороны, вы можете просто добавить классу `.jconfirm-box-container` свойство `margin-left: 33.33333333%;`, повторяющее оригинальное правило. Тогда тоже все станет нормально. Хотя не уверен в гибкости подобного подхода. Как минимум, не должна меняться ширина окна, иначе оно "уедет".